# Running forecast in a loop python (Python newbie trying to learn)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a dataframe with columns date, sales.
I ran a ETS model using the code below:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.holtwinters import ExponentialSmoothing
m = ExponentialSmoothing(df.sales,trend='mul',seasonal='mul',seasonal_periods=12).fit()
forecast=m.forecast(13)
forecast= pd.DataFrame(m.forecast(13),columns=['sales'])
```

I am trying to run this on another dataframe with has date, region and sales
this is what I am trying, please find code below:

```
test_df = pd.DataFrame() ## creating empty data frame##
for region in df: ## trying to iterate over each region##
    test_df['region'] = unique_regions ## trying to add the region value to the empty data drame##
    m = ExponentialSmoothing(df.sales,trend='mul',seasonal='mul',seasonal_periods=12).fit()
    forecast=m.forecast(13)
    forecast= pd.DataFrame(m.forecast(13),columns=['sales'])
    column=df['date']
    max_date=column.max()
    date_list=pd.date_range(start=max_date, periods=14, freq='M')
    date_list=pd.DataFrame(date_list,columns=['date'])
    date_list=date_list.iloc[1:,0]
    date_list=pd.DataFrame(date_list)
    date_list.reset_index()
    date_list.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
    forecast.reset_index(inplace=True,drop=True)
    test_df=forecast.join(date_list,how='outer')
    test_df = test_df[['date','region', 'sales']] ## finally create a df with date,region and the forecasted value##
test_df

## append the test_df to df##
```

**Could someone please assist? How do I run the model over each region**

Comment: What exactly is the question? - How to create a datafame with the regions? How to train the model on seperate data slices...?

Comment: Run a model on separate data slices. I need to run the ets model by each region

Comment: Then you can do two things. Slice your dataframe with conditions + .query() or .loc[] or use group_by(). Give it a shot. Tomorrow i might have the time to give you a short code example.